# Getting json value from httpclient post request

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the modhash value from a returned json string, I have set my getter/setter

```
public string mod_hash { get; set; }
```

I am using `httclient`, how can I get the json value of mod_hash
To post data:

```
        /
```

Comment: `int modhashPosition = responseString.IndexOf("modhash"); int commaPosition = responseString.IndexOf(",", modhashPosition); string result = responseString.Substring(modhashPosition + 11, commaPosition - modhashPosition - 12).Trim();` :D Just kidding, please don't...

Comment: Being serious, you can a library JSON.NET to parse your string and access this property. There are really many similar questions and answers at SO about parsing JSON. For example, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: I noticed you're trying to set `mod_hash` by setting `modhash`.  Try renaming your property to `modhash` without the underscore, or try setting `mod_hash` with underscore in the javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below one.

To deserialize,you need to create the proper class structure for the json string. As per your json string, i have created here. Try and let us know if you have still issues.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Json json { get; set; }
}
public class Json
{
    public List<object> errors { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
public class Data
{
    public bool need_https { get; set; }
    public string modhash { get; set; }
    public string cookie { get; set; }
}
```

And to test if it is correct or not here i have the program to get the "modhash" property value from your json string.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string jsonstring = @"{ ""json"": {""errors"": [],""data"": { ""need_https"": true, ""modhash"": ""valuehereremoved"",""cookie"": ""valuehereremoved"" } } }";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonstring);
        Console.WriteLine("modhash : " + jsonObject.json.data.modhash);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Hope it solves your problem.